# Can I specify a mysql database where certain liquibase changesets should only be executed or should I be create a new file with required changesets

Tags: mysql, liquibase

Consider I have multiple databases DB1 & DB2. Both changesets must be
executed in DB1 but id="12" only in DB2.

Following are the changeset format I have used written in
**db-install.xml**. Is there any better approach.

```
<changeSet id="11" author="root">
    <sql> <![CDATA[     
         INSERT INTO 'DB1.item_status` (`id`, `status`) 
       VALUES
        (1, 'added'),
        (2, 'sold'),
        (3,'unsold'),
        (4,'updated');  
                ]]>
    </sql>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="12" author="root">
    <sql> <![CDATA[     
         INSERT INTO `item_details` (`id`, `state`) 
       VALUES
        (1, 'Very Strong'),
        (2, 'Strong'),
        (3,'Medium'),
        (4,'Faint'),
        (5,'None'); 
                ]]>
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: you can set [defaultSchemaName](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/commands/maven-update.html)

Comment: @bilak, As per my understanding from [https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/commands/maven-update.html]docs, degfaultSchemaName is not changeset specific. Its for entire file or can I use like <changeSet id="11" author="root" defaultSchemaName="DB1">

Comment: It's not very clear to me what do you want to achieve. Maybe try to look at context parameter. Or maybe also some substitution of parameters can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe **Liquibase Contexts** is what you are looking for and will help you.

Let's consider you have 2 contexts as "DB1" and "DB2". Also assume you have below two changesets in your project:

```
<changeSet id="11" author="root" context="DB1,DB2">
    <sql> <![CDATA[     
         INSERT INTO 'DB1.item_status` (`id`, `status`) 
       VALUES
        (1, 'added'),
        (2, 'sold'),
        (3,'unsold'),
        (4,'updated');  
                ]]>
    </sql>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="12" author="root" context="DB1">
    <sql> <![CDATA[     
         INSERT INTO `item_details` (`id`, `state`) 
       VALUES
        (1, 'Very Strong'),
        (2, 'Strong'),
        (3,'Medium'),
        (4,'Faint'),
        (5,'None'); 
                ]]>
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Let's say you are running liquibase with following command:
`liquibase --changeLogFile=changelog.xml --contexts="DB2" update`

Specifying context *DB2* while running liquibase will only run the changesets whose contexts have "*DB2*" as a value. In the above example, the changeset with *id=11* has *"DB2"* context however the changetset with *id=12* doesn't have *"DB2"* as a context value. Hence on running liquibase, changeset with *id=12 will only be executed when you provide context value as "DB1"*.

Please go through [this link](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/contexts.html) which explains more on liquibase contexts and it's use.

Cheers!